# Special characters in javascript onClick paramerters

Tags: javascript, onclick, special-characters

I have a javascript `onclick` function. I am passing certain values which has special characters inside `onclick`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="editLocation(34:B1:F7:D5:BB:52)">click</a>
```

which gives me an error

[image]

How do i pass all the value inside `onclick`.. I don't want to ignore special character. I must pass the complete value 34:B1:F7:D5:BB:52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add single quotes, like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="editLocation('34:B1:F7:D5:BB:52')">click</a>
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/sezoha/1/edit?html,output)